# Enviar email No LocalHost ou Servidor sem Mail()

Tags: php, pdo, phpmailer

Olá, tenho o sistema `PHP` abaixo para realizar o cadastro após o submit do usuário, o cadastro ocorre normalmente, porém eu gostaria que fosse enviado um email para o email cadastrado, porém da forma que eu fiz não está sendo enviado, alguém pode dar uma ajuda? Desde já agradeço

```
<?php   
require_once('classes/conecta.cadastro.php');
$pdo = conectar();

    // RECEBENDO OS DADOS PREENCHIDOS DO FORMULÁRIO !
    $nome   = $_POST ["nome"];
    $data   = $_POST ["data"];
    $sexo   = $_POST ["sexo"];
    $email  = $_POST ["email"];
    $email2 = $_POST ["email2"];
    $senha  = sha1($_POST ["senha"]);
    $senha1 = sha1($_POST ["senha1"]);
    $cpf    = $_POST ["cpf"];
    $tel    = $_POST ["tel"];
    $cel    = $_POST ["cel"];
    $cep    = $_POST ["cep"];
    $rua    = $_POST ["rua"];
    $numero = $_POST ["numero"];
    $bairro = $_POST ["bairro"];
    $cidade = $_POST ["cidade"];
    $uf     = $_POST ["uf"];
    if ($instituicao = "OUTRA") {
        $instituicao = $_POST ["outrainst"];
    } else{
        $instituicao    = $_POST ["instituição"];
    }
    $nivel  = $_POST ["nivel"];
    $curso  = $_POST ["curso"];
    $area   = $_POST ["area"];

    $turno  = $_POST ["turno"];
    $palestras  = $_POST ["palestras"];
    $cidade2    = $_POST ["cidade2"];   

    if(!empty($_POST['dias']) && count($_POST['dias']) ){
       $chgeckboxes = $_POST['dias'];
       //implode
       $horario = implode(',', $_POST['dias']);
    }

    if(!empty($_POST['Habilidades']) && count($_POST['Habilidades']) ){
       $chgeckboxes = $_POST['Habilidades'];
       //implode
       $habilidades = implode(',', $_POST['Habilidades']);
    }


    $arq = $_FILES['foto']['name'];

    $arq = $_FILES['foto']['name'];

    $arq = str_replace(" ", "_", $arq);
    $arq = str_replace("ç", "c", $arq);

    if (file_exists("imagens/".$arq)) {
        $a = 1;

        while (file_exists("imagens/[".$a."]".$arq)) {
            $a++;
        }

        $arq = "[".$a."]".$arq;
    }

    $foto = $arq;
    $aprovado = '0';

    //Prepara o cadastro
    $cadastro = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO dados (nome, data, sexo, email, email2, senha, senha1, cpf, tel, cel, cep, rua, numero, bairro, cidade, uf, instituicao, nivel, curso, area, turno, horario, habilidades, palestras, cidade2, foto, aprovado) VALUES (:nome, :data, :sexo, :email, :email2, :senha, :senha1, :cpf, :tel, :cel, :cep, :rua, :numero, :bairro, :cidade, :uf, :instituicao, :nivel, :curso, :area, :turno, :horario, :habilidades, :palestras, :cidade2, :foto, :aprovado)");

    $cadastro->bindValue(":nome",$nome);
    $cadastro->bindValue(":data",$data);
    $cadastro->bindValue(":sexo",$sexo);
    $cadastro->bindValue(":email",$email);
    $cadastro->bindValue(":email2",$email2);
    $cadastro->bindValue(":senha",$senha);
    $cadastro->bindValue(":senha1",$senha1);
    $cadastro->bindValue(":cpf",$cpf);
    $cadastro->bindValue(":tel",$tel);
    $cadastro->bindValue(":cel",$cel);
    $cadastro->bindValue(":cep",$cep);
    $cadastro->bindValue(":rua",$rua);
    $cadastro->bindValue(":numero",$numero);
    $cadastro->bindValue(":bairro",$bairro);
    $cadastro->bindValue(":cidade",$cidade);
    $cadastro->bindValue(":uf",$uf);
    $cadastro->bindValue(":instituicao",$instituicao);
    $cadastro->bindValue(":nivel",$nivel);
    $cadastro->bindValue(":curso",$curso);
    $cadastro->bindValue(":area",$area);
    $cadastro->bindValue(":turno",$turno);
    $cadastro->bindValue(":horario",$horario);
    $cadastro->bindValue(":habilidades",$habilidades);
    $cadastro->bindValue(":palestras",$palestras);
    $cadastro->bindValue(":cidade2",$cidade2);
    $cadastro->bindValue(":foto",$foto);
    $cadastro->bindValue(":aprovado",$aprovado);
    //Valida o cadastro
    $validar = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tab_clientes WHERE email = ?");
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'], 'imagens/'.$arq)) {
        //Executa o cadastro
        $retorno = $cadastro->execute(); 
        if ($retorno){
            //Enviando email de confirmação de cadastro
            $assunto = "Cadastro realizado";
            $mensagem = "Seu cadastro foi realizado, em breve entraremos em 
contato!
";
            $header = "From: teste@teste.com";
            mail($email, $assunto, $mensagem, $header);
            header('Location: succes.php');

        } else {
            ini_set("display_errors",1);
            ini_set("display_startup_erros",1);
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
            header('Location: cadastro.php?erro=1');
        }

    } else{
        header('Location: cadastro.php?erro=1');
    } 
?>
```

Conexão com o banco de dados via PDO:

```
<?php

function conectar(){
try{
    $pdo=new PDO("mysql:host=ffgdfgdfgdfgr;dbname=fdgdfg"
    ,"fdgdfg","dfgdfgdfg");
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
    return $pdo;
}

?>
```

Comment: vc está utlizando local host ? caso não  verifique se o servidor que hospeda o site tem  acess ao mail(), alguns servidores só funcionam com smtp

Comment: Usa a classe phpmailer, já soluciona o problema a cima
Segundo, no localhost o mailer não funciona

Comment: @MarcosBrinnerpikatoons Eu tentei tanto pelo local host quando usando um servidor, no caso o `locaweb`, você sabe se ele tem acesso ao `mail()`?

Comment: localhost não funcionaria nunca...

Comment: @gabrielfalieri Sim, eu imaginei que por lá não daria mesmo, mas eu tentei também pelo Locaweb, porém sem sucesso também!

Comment: no  localhost não dá para enviar, ai  vc  teria que configurar seu servidor de mail, mas  é um pouco complexo,  no locaweb você terá que utilizar o  mailer veja como  em [mailer locaweb](https://ajuda.locaweb.com.br/pt-br/Enviar_e-mails_pelo_PHP_usando_o_PHPMailer)

Comment: na  verdade eles possuem  um tutorial que pode te ajudar [mail() locaweb](https://ajuda.locaweb.com.br/pt-br/Como_enviar_e-mails_com_a_fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o_mail()_do_PHP)

Comment: @MarcosBrinnerpikatoons muito obrigado, vou olhar os tutoriais deles e usar o PHPMailer, muito obrigado mesmo!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como detectamos o seu servidor não está funcionando com  o mail() do php Há algumas  alternativas uma delas é o  Mailer() que é uma classe que utliza-se de requisição smtp [**Download MailerPHP**](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/email/send-email-from-a-page/download-phpmailer)

Apos fazer o download extraia para seu  diretorio
e chame as  class no  aquivo que deseja enviar o  email

**require_once("class/class.phpmailer.php");**

Apos isso basta adicionar o seguinte codigo

```
// Inicia a classe PHPMailer
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

// Define os dados do servidor e tipo de conexão
// =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
$mail->IsSMTP(); // Define que a mensagem será SMTP


 try {
 $mail->Host = 'smtp.seudominio.com.br'; // Endereço do servidor SMTP (Autenticação, utilize o host smtp.seudomínio.com.br)
 $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;  // Usar autenticação SMTP (obrigatório para smtp.seudomínio.com.br)
 $mail->Port       = 587; //  Usar 587 porta SMTP
 $mail->Username = 'usuário de smtp'; // Usuário do servidor SMTP (endereço de email)
 $mail->Password = 'senha de smtp'; // Senha do servidor SMTP (senha do email usado)

 //Define o remetente
 // =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=    
 $mail->SetFrom('seu@e-mail.com.br', 'Nome'); //Seu e-mail
 $mail->AddReplyTo('seu@e-mail.com.br', 'Nome'); //Seu e-mail
 $mail->Subject = 'Assunto';//Assunto do e-mail


 //Define os destinatário(s)
 //=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
 $mail->AddAddress('e-mail@destino.com.br', 'Teste Locaweb');

 //Campos abaixo são opcionais 
 //=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
 //$mail->AddCC('destinarario@dominio.com.br', 'Destinatario'); // Copia
 //$mail->AddBCC('destinatario_oculto@dominio.com.br', 'Destinatario2`'); // Cópia Oculta
 //$mail->AddAttachment('images/phpmailer.gif');      // Adicionar um anexo


 //Define o corpo do email
 $mail->MsgHTML('corpo do email'); 

 ////Caso queira colocar o conteudo de um arquivo utilize o método abaixo ao invés da mensagem no corpo do e-mail.
 //$mail->MsgHTML(file_get_contents('arquivo.html'));

 $mail->Send();
 echo "Mensagem enviada com sucesso</p>\n";

//caso apresente algum erro é apresentado abaixo com essa exceção.
}catch (phpmailerException $e) {
  echo $e->errorMessage(); //Mensagem de erro costumizada do PHPMailer
}
```

Lembrando que você precisará de usuarios validos de email no  servidor para utilza-lo

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, vou tentar usar esse método!!